# MS CRM - Getting Wrong date through CRM Webservice

Tags: date, datetime, window, dynamics-crm

When I retrieve an entity through the crm webservice (CRM SDK) I receive on one Server a really strange behavior. 
In the CRM (webinterface) the stored date (dateonly) is : 18.02.2019 (UTC+1)
The Database shows : 17.02.2019 23:00:00 (UTC)

At this part, all is correct.
But when I retrieve the record on a console app (=running on the CRM server) the mentioned field is set to **18.02.2019 23:00:00** (so 19.02.2019 in UTC+1).
Running the application localy (on my pc) it returns the correct datetime **17.02.2019 23:00:00**. 
Is there a serversetting or so which I missed? 
The timezone on the server is UTC+1 Amsterdam,Berlin.

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with the DateTime's [Kind property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.kind?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the console app.

You might be able to resolve this with:
 `DateTime.SpecifyKind(myDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Or simply:
 `myDateTime.ToUniversalTime()`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different [Behavior and format of the date and time attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/behavior-format-date-time-attribute). Depending on your situation I suspect one of these will explain the behaviour you are seeing.

> UserLocal
>
> - The retrieve operation returns the UTC value.
> - Retrieving the formatted value converts from UTC to the user’s current time zone based on the time zone and locale setting of the
>     user.
>
> DateOnly
>
> - For the retrieve and update operations, no time zone conversion is performed, and the time value is always 12 AM (00:00:00).
> - Retrieving the formatted value displays the date value without any time zone conversion.
>
> TimeZoneIndependent
>
> - For the retrieve and update operations, no time zone conversion is    performed, and actual date and time values are returned and updated
>     respectively in the system regardless of the user time zone.
> - Retrieving the formatted value displays the date and time value    (without any time zone conversion) based on the format as specified
>     by the current user’s time zone and locale setting.